# How to run Quamotion tests on macOS TeamCity agents

Tags: macos, testing, mobile, webdriver, teamcity

I'm trying to integrate Quamotion in our TeamCity platform so we can test mobile apps in our CI process.

I've followed the steps described [in the Quamotion documentation](http://docs.quamotion.mobi/en/latest/how-to/run-mobile-ui-tests-in-teamcity.html).

The Build-Steps and Build-Feature have been added but I'm seeing an error on our agents:

- Incompatible runner: PowerShell
- Unmet requirements: Exists=>(powershell_x86|powershell_x64) exists

PowerShell has been installed on our build server and we can run Quamotion without any errors: I can see the mobile devices which are connected to my build server, install apps, run tests,... . I've tried restarting and reinstalling the agent but that didn't fix it either.

Is there anything I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like either PowerShell core is not installed on your TeamCity agent or you're not using an up-to-date version of TeamCity.

To check whether PowerShell Core has been installed, open a Terminal on your agent and run `pwsh`. If that opens a PowerShell terminal, PowerShell Core has been installed correctly.

From what I can see, support for PowerShell Core has been added to TeamCity 2017.2.2. Can you make sure you're using TeamCity 2017.2.2 or later?

Answer (score 0):

Please note: If Powershell Core is installed using the *zipped* version and manual placement of the unzipped folder, place it in the same folder as the MSI installation does, which is:

```
%programfiles%\Powershell\6
%programfiles(x86)%\Powershell\6
```

These are the folders that the TeamCity build agent search through to find the PS Core installation. If the TeamCity build agent find the installation folders, it sets the variables accordingly:

(example, PS Core x64 bitness)

```
powershell_Core_6.1.0_x64        6.1.0
powershell_Core_6.1.0_x64_Path   C:\Program Files\PowerShell\6
powershell_Core_x64              6.1.0
```